# How to model data from JSON array with no property name into swift so It can be parsed? SWIFT

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

Im stuck trying to model a JSON array which has no property name into my swift project with the goal of parsing the data and using it in my app. I know how to do this when there is a NAME for the array but I don't know how to make swift and this lackluster JSON understand each other. The path to the first "Company" in the JSON is "0.Company". The error I get is "Value of type 'WorkData' has no member '0'"
 Im including pictures of my full project so it is easier to understand the structure of the code and what im trying to do. Please look at the picture for a clearer understanding I apologize if Im not explaining it well i'm new to programming.

```
    import Foundation

class WorkData: Codable {
    let WorkData: [WorkData]
    let Company: String
    let worklogDate: String
    let issue: String
}
```

```
    func parseData(jsonDataInput: Data) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder() // an object that decodes JSON data
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(WorkData.self, from: jsonDataInput)
            let Company = decodedData.0.Company
            let worklogDate = decodedData.0.worklogDate
            let issue = decodedData.0.issue


        } catch {
            print (error)
        }
    }

}
```

[json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iIgn.png)
[Trying to model JSON in Swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnaFd.jpg)

[Parsing JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFHjp.jpg)

Comment: remove the `WorkData` property from the struct. Also understand that an array with a key (name property) is a dictionary and an array is just that, an array of `WorkData` objects and nothing else is needed since an array of Codable objects also conforms to Codable and can be encoded to json.

Comment: Stop adding pictures of code, add the code as text to the question.

Comment: To parse an array of an object, you need to decode with `[MyObject].self`.  Remove the `WorkData` property and decode as `[WorkData].self`

Comment: When I remove the WorkData property from the struct I still have the errors in my third image I added to the post. Please take a look at the image "Parsing JSON"

Comment: That's because you would have an array as the result, not a tuple.  `...decoded([WorkData].self...` and access the first element the same way you would an array.  `decodedData[0].Company`

Comment: So to conclude: 1) remove `WorkData` property from struct 2) decode as array `.decode([WorkData].self, ...` 3) access values using an index `decodedData[0]` or use a loop `for item in decodedData {...`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot start JSON with an array because JSON itself is an object {}

See example below:

```
{
    "WorkData" : [
                   {"Company" : ""},
                   {"Company" : ""},
                   {"Company" : ""}                                           
     ]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
let decodedData = try decoder.decode(LocalizationsResponse.self, from: jsonDataInput)
```

decodedData will be an array